# Part of iframe content as image

Tags: javascript, image, iframe

Can I get an image out of a part of an iframe content?

let's say the the code (pseudocode) below

```
<iframe>
  ...
   <body>
     ...
     <div id="wantToRender">Test</div>
   </body>
  ...
</iframe>
```

can i get some how the wantToRender div content rendered as an image inside js?